# In jQuery $(this) don't return me the current element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show a particular text an icon depending cases.

For example, if datas are successfully saved I show a 'Your datas are saved.' and the right icon.

My problem is before the `$.ajax` part, all is working but after, I think my `$(this).find(...)` don't return me the element.

Is it possible ?

Here's my code:

```
$('form.modal-form').on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    icon = 'fa-spinner fa-pulse';
    text = 'Save in progress';
    $(this).find('.modal-footer .pull-left').html('<i class="fa ' + icon + ' fa-fw"></i><span class="hidden-xs">' + text + '</span>');



    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        data : $(this).serialize(),
        url  : 'assets/php/ajax/'+$(this).data('target')+'.php',
        success: function(response){
            var json = $.parseJSON(response);
            if(json.type=='success'){
                icon = 'fa-check';
                text = json.message;
                $(this).find('.modal-footer .pull-left').html('<i class="fa ' + icon + ' fa-fw"></i><span class="hidden-xs">' + text + '</span>');
            }
            if(json.type=='error'){
                icon = 'fa-exclamation';
                text = json.message;
                $(this).find('.modal-footer .pull-left').html('<i class="fa ' + icon + ' fa-fw"></i><span class="hidden-xs">' + text + '</span>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Again and again. `this` is not this before you run something asynchronous . Set `this` to `somehingElse` before you run `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ajax callback `this` refers to a different object from the one in the `submit` handler, so not to lose it, you should assign it to something in the first place (*to make it visible in the callback afterwards*),  after `event.preventDefault`, for example:

```
var that = $(this)
```

And use `that` instead of `$(this)`.

Comment: there is also a `context` option in `$.ajax({context:this, url:...` which can be helpful